# AJAX user login not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I really get angry on my code so I'm confused for two days about this code.
I'm using jquery and ajax to login my user but the problem is ajax not working and my login page refresh automatic!!
when i submit form the submit event wake up but the ajax code in it doesn't work!
please someone help me by this code i really appreciate it.

here is my login.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Basics -->

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Login</title>

    <!-- CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reg.css"/>
    <script src="./jqlib/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#login").submit(function()
        {



            $.ajax({

                url: 'loginopr.php',
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'html',
                    data:"phone="+$('#phone').val()+"&password="+$('#password').val(),
                success:function(response){
                    if(response == "2")
                        alert("شماره تلفن یا رمز عبور وارد شده اشتباه می باشد");

                    else{ if(response=="3")
                        alert("لطفا اطلاعات را به طرز درست وارد کنید");
                        }

                    }


                    });


    });



    }); 





    </script>



</head>

    <!-- Main HTML -->

<body>

    <!-- Begin Page Content -->

    <div id="container">

        <form  method="POST">

        <label for="name">تلفن همراه :</label>

        <input type="tel" required="" title="لطفا شماره همراه خود را به صورت صحیح وارد نمایید" x-moz-errormessage="لط
        فا شماره همراه خود را به صورت صحیح وارد نمایید" name="phone" id="phone">

        <label for="username">رمز عبور :</label>

        <input  type="password" required="" id="password" title="رمز عبور را وارد کنید" x-moz-errormessage="رمز عبور را وارد کنید" name="password">

        <div id="lower">

        <input type="checkbox"><label class="check" for="checkbox">مرا بخاطر بسپار</label>


        <input type="submit" value="ورود" id="login" ><br />
        <a style=" float: right; clear:both; margin-right: 10px;margin-bottom:10px; text-decoration: blink;" href="register.php">ثبتنام نکرده ام</a>
        </div>

        </form>
        <div class="footer">
            <div>
                    <a href="http://hameja123.ir">همه جا 123</a>
            </div>
                    کلیه حقوق این سایت محفوظ بوده و متعلق به
                    <a href="http://hameja123.ir">همه جا 123</a>
                    می‌باشد.
            <div style="direction:ltr; color: #ffffff;">hameja.ir - Copyright © 2013 - All rights reserved by Reza Tanzifi.</div>

        </div><!--end footer-->
    </div>


    <!-- End Page Content -->




</body>

</html>
```

here is my loginopr.php

```
<?php

include_once 'includes/function.php';
include_once 'user.php';
$user = new User();
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        if(isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['password']) )
        {
            $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
            $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

        $login = $user->check_login($phone, $password);
            if ($login)
             {
// Login Success
                 header("location : buy-charge.php");

             }
        else
             {
        // Login Failed
                return 2;
             }
        }
    else {
        //field are empty
        return 3;
         }
    }
?>
```

i think the problem is about my ajax code and its about client side
i'm waiting for your answers
thanks alot ;)

Comment: Please give more detail than 'not working'. Does the request get sent? Is there anything in the network traffic in F12 dev tools? Is there an error in your server logs?

Comment: isnt it `data: { phone : $('#phone').val() , password : $('password').val(); }` ? and must use `echo` and not return

Comment: no the request doesn't send  when i check it in console of firebug. i don't know wht the ajax code did not working, what do you mean by F12 dev tools? i'm beginner not proffesioanl :)

Comment: Drixson i didnt use JSON for data transaction i'm just send data in html line.

Comment: @user2668753 he means dev tools for example firebug , it really can help you in your development. Please see my answer below a better structure of passing your POST values.

Comment: i use firebug in firefox ;) but there is no transfer when i submit form and just my login.php page refresh again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are clicking a submit button it shoud submit, doesn't matter if you attached AJAX on it. To fix that change your `$("#login").submit(function(){...});` to

```
   $("#login").click(function(event){

        event.preventDefault(); // cancel the default action, i.e submiting the form

        // proceed to your AJAX:
        ... 

    });
```

Also change `return` to `echo` in your PHP part. Here `result` is what is seen on the page, I mean what is printed out there, with all html, text etc.

And as already said few times here

```
data: { 
    phone : $('#phone').val() , 
    password : $('password').val()
}
```

Comment: hey console tell me that preventDefault() not defined :?

Comment: Edited abit, please try again. .click(function(event){...});

Comment: hey after data: { 
    phone : $('#phone').val() , 
    password : $('password').val()
} should i set ; or , ??

Comment: data: { phone : $('#phone').val() , password : $('password').val() },

Comment: you should set "," if something comes after it, like in your case "success:function(){...}" or you set nothing if nothing comes after it

Answer (score 1):

when submitting your form it is not `$('#login').submit();` you're script telling this to submit your form, if you want to run your ajax it should be:

```
$('#login').click(function(){

   //your ajax script here

  //to stop sending your form
  event.preventDefault();

});
```

and

I should recommend you when passing data variables to your php it should be like this:

```
data: { 
 phone : $('#phone').val() , 
 password : $('password').val()
}
```

and in your php when returning your response to ajax you should `echo` it

```
echo '2'; // or echo 'invalid';
```

Comment: it didn't work!! do i need to change my datatype when i use json?

Comment: let me refine my answer I missed something. You dont need to change the datatype to json.. It means what datatype is your response

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#login").submit
```

#login must be form

```
<form  method="POST" id='#login'>
...
...
</form>
```

Comment: Negative! i'm still on the client side and my request doesn't send man, so echo used for show some thing, am i right?

Comment: thanks man it works but there is another problem appear, the alert function doesnot work and my login.php still refresh again :?

Comment: use echo instead return in php

Comment: i use echo but no answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this . I have changed your front end code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Basics -->

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Login</title>

    <!-- CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reg.css"/>
    <script src="./jqlib/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#login").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:'loginopr.php',
            type:"POST",
            dataType: 'html',
          data:
              {
               "phone":$('#phone').val(),
               "password":$('#password').val()
               },
         success:function(response){
        if(response == "2")
               alert("شماره تلفن یا رمز عبور وارد شده اشتباه می باشد");
       else{ if(response=="3")
                       alert("لطفا اطلاعات را به طرز درست وارد کنید");
                       }

    }});
  });
});
    </script>



</head>

    <!-- Main HTML -->

<body>

    <!-- Begin Page Content -->

    <div id="container">

        <form  method="POST">

        <label for="name">تلفن همراه :</label>

        <input type="tel" required="" title="لطفا شماره همراه خود را به صورت صحیح وارد نمایید" x-moz-errormessage="لط
        فا شماره همراه خود را به صورت صحیح وارد نمایید" name="phone" id="phone">

        <label for="username">رمز عبور :</label>

        <input  type="password" required="" id="password" title="رمز عبور را وارد کنید" x-moz-errormessage="رمز عبور را وارد کنید" name="password">

        <div id="lower">

        <input type="checkbox"><label class="check" for="checkbox">مرا بخاطر بسپار</label>


        <input type="button" value="ورود" id="login" ><br />
        <a style=" float: right; clear:both; margin-right: 10px;margin-bottom:10px; text-decoration: blink;" href="register.php">ثبتنام نکرده ام</a>
        </div>

        </form>
        <div class="footer">
            <div>
                    <a href="http://hameja123.ir">همه جا 123</a>
            </div>
                    کلیه حقوق این سایت محفوظ بوده و متعلق به
                    <a href="http://hameja123.ir">همه جا 123</a>
                    می‌باشد.
            <div style="direction:ltr; color: #ffffff;">hameja.ir - Copyright © 2013 - All rights reserved by Reza Tanzifi.</div>

        </div><!--end footer-->
    </div>


    <!-- End Page Content -->




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yes man i know it works but if you insert submit button you should prevent the call event that this method use so i prevent the event and call my event anyway thanks alot it worked ;)